# Running a node application with WSL2

Tags: node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run node app using WSL. I added remote extension on VS Code, installed node on ubuntu successfully. Also when i run the program `node server.js` it shows this:
[image]

But when i try to redirect from my browser in windows. It says `127.0.0.1 refused to connect`. How can i solve this issue?

Edit: Basically i am running app successfully on ubuntu WSL but when i try to open it with browser in windows i can not access it.

Comment: Just `127.0.0.1`, or `127.0.0.1:3000`?

Comment: in server.js, the port 3000 is listening so ``` 127.0.0.1:3000 ```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of input/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code to listen to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1

```
const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3000;

// Your server setup code...

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

run your code `node server.js`

Check the IP address assigned to your WSL instance. You can do this by running the following command in WSL:

```
ip addr show eth0
```

The IP address you need is the one next to inet under the eth0 interface